# Go away, 2-minute tour!

Tags: discussion, new-users

I clicked on a hot question on *Skeptics* and, at the top of the question, was asked to take the 2-minute tour. "Sure."
To me, this tour seems presented as an overlay over existing content (the question I was reading) because of its drop shadow and the dimmed appearance of content underneath.
In the context of this interpretation, I expect to see a way to close the tour and reveal the question I was reading, but it appears to be uncloseable. AdBlock revealed that the tour is no overlay but an entirely different page. That's fine, but I think this can upset new users and therefore the tour either be made closeable or no longer imply through visual cues that it is an overlay at all.

Comment: Each of the SE sites is different with their policies, and you should probably invest those two minutes.

Comment: _I think this can upset new users_ Why? Aside from the answer below showing how to close it, why would this be upsetting to new users? It's information they need to know anyway.

Answer (score 8):

There is a minimize button on the initial banner:

[image: Skeptics Minimize Button]

When you click that, there is a close button on the smaller banner:

[image: Skeptics close button]

Both of these appear with AdBlock active, for me.